# How to change the font size of a script?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

Good, the reason that leads me to ask, once again, your help is this, I have a script that gives me data from an XML document, what I wanted to do was change the font of font, size ... the script but I'm not able to run it!

Here I leave the script I'm trying to change what I want.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
var speed = 20000; // 20 seconds

//http://code.google.com/p/miniajax/
function $(e){if(typeof e=='string')e=document.getElementById(e);return e};
function collect(a,f){var n=[];for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){var v=f(a[i]);if(v!=null)n.push(v)}return n};

ajax={};
ajax.x=function(){try{return new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP')}catch(e){try{return new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP')}catch(e){return new XMLHttpRequest()}}};
ajax.serialize=function(f){var g=function(n){return f.getElementsByTagName(n)};var nv=function(e){if(e.name)return encodeURIComponent(e.name)+'='+encodeURIComponent(e.value);else return ''};var i=collect(g('input'),function(i){if((i.type!='radio'&&i.type!='checkbox')||i.checked)return nv(i)});var s=collect(g('select'),nv);var t=collect(g('textarea'),nv);return i.concat(s).concat(t).join('&');};
ajax.send=function(u,f,m,a){var x=ajax.x();x.open(m,u,true);x.onreadystatechange=function(){if(x.readyState==4)f(x.responseText)};if(m=='POST')x.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');x.send(a)};
ajax.get=function(url,func){ajax.send(url,func,'GET')};
ajax.gets=function(url){var x=ajax.x();x.open('GET',url,false);x.send(null);return x.responseText};
ajax.post=function(url,func,args){ajax.send(url,func,'POST',args)};
ajax.update=function(url,elm){var e=$(elm);var f=function(r){e.innerHTML=r};ajax.get(url,f)};
ajax.submit=function(url,elm,frm){var e=$(elm);var f=function(r){e.innerHTML=r};ajax.post(url,f,ajax.serialize(frm))};

function process(xml) {
  document.getElementById('contentfile').innerHTML=xml;
  var title = document.getElementById('contentfile').getElementsByTagName('song')[0].title;
  var name = document.getElementById('contentfile').getElementsByTagName('Artist')[0].getAttribute('name');
  document.getElementById('contentfile').innerHTML=' '+name+' - ' +title;
}
function checkXml() {
  ajax.get('/NowOnAir.xml',process)
}
window.onload=function() {
  checkXml();
  tId=setInterval('checkXml()',speed)  
}

</script>

<link rel="Stylesheet" href="/player.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="contentfile">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the formula that I'm trying to change the size of the font (CSS)

```css
.innerHTML {
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-style: normal;
    word-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 30px;


}
```

Can you please help me doing this?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Are you changing the value for `font-size: 28px;`?  Change the `28` to a different number **EG:** `font-size: 16px;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.blah` selector in CSS refers to items which have a **class** of *blah*, for example`<div class='blah'>` -- you have no item with a class of `innerHTML`.  Your `<div>` has an `id` of `contentfile`.  In CSS, the '#' symbol is used for `id` selection.

Thus, your css should be:

```
#contentfile {
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-style: normal;
    word-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Look closer at the JS?????

Comment: @Charles Jaimet Already got what I wanted with your help, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @AndréSantos

Answer (score 0):

change the value of `font-size: 11pt` or some equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

Are you changing the value for `font-size: 28px;`?

Change the `28` to a different number **EG**:

`font-size: 16px;`

Comment: Thank you to all who responded to this post, following the technique of Charles Jaimet, I could accomplish what I wanted, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

```
head{
    font-family: "Oswald", sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-style: normal;
    word-spacing: 1px;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Why would you apply this to `head`?